# She doesn’t have any brothers or sisters. (with "any" and without)

Tags: determiners

Am I right that the first sentence is more common than the second one?

As I understand, the first sentence has more emotional emphasis, isn't it?

> She doesn’t have any brothers or sisters.

> She doesn’t have brothers or sisters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that *any* adds emphasis to the fact of not having siblings, and would be more commonly used standing alone.  For instance as in a simple factual reply in a conversation.  Using *any* with this kind of negative statement is also especially preferred in response to a question, or an assertion by someone else to the contrary.

Comment: The first is likely to be the answer to "How many siblings does she have?"